# How would I change the default loaded view controller in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How would I do this? Is it simple enough to explain clearly? If not, a tutorial would be nice. I checked the web and this site and still couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Most of the templates do this in the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default XIB file loaded when your application start is MainWindow.xib by default.

If you want you app to load another XIB instead, this can be changed **in the Info.plist file** of your project.

In this XIB loaded when the app is launched (MainWindow.XIB by default), you will find:

- a placeholder for the `File's Owner` (like in any XIB) which in the case of the XIB loaded by the application on startup is the UIApplication itself.
- a UIWindow (the main and unique window of your iPhone app),
- an object that acts as the delegate of your UIApplication (commonly called "the AppDelegate")
- And probably a UIViewController too.

When the XIB is loaded at startup, the AppDelegate objet is instanciated (like all objects in the XIB except the File's Owner) and as it is set as the delegate of the application, `application:didFinishLaunhcingWithOptions:` will be executed. This code then generally add the viewController's view as a subview of your app window using a line like `[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view]`. (As your AppDelegate have an IBOutlet that points to the ViewController in the XIB)

---

If you need to change the class of the ViewController used in your MainWindow.xib, change the class of the UIViewController in Interface Builder, and also change the type of the associated IBOutlet in the AppDelegate header file.

Comment: how would i change this in the info.plist?

Comment: Errr... open the Info.plist in Xcode and change the corresponding line, that's all. See [the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) and especially [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1). As explained in the doc, the corresponding key is `NSMainNibFile`, which is displayed in a human-readable manner as "Main nib file base name”.